# Why doesn't C need '&' in scanf() while dealing with strings/char

Tags: c, pointers

My code is very simple just basic IO. Now when I use this code it works perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age = 0;
    char name[100]; //Unlike c++ We need to specify char limit instead of "Name", so name can't go above 99 char + 1 terinator
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);// dont need & for char
    printf("Your name is %s and your age is %d\n", name, age);
    return 0;
}
```

Now

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age = 0;
    char name[100]; //Unlike c++ We need to specify char limit instead of "Name", so name can't go above 99 char + 1 terinator
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);// dont need & for char
    printf("Your name is %s and your age is %d\n", name, age);
    return 0;
}
```

when I make changes in line 10. and add &name. compiler throws this error. Why is that?

```
p2.c:10:17: error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[100]' [-Werror,-Wformat]
    scanf("%s", &name);// dont need & for char
           ~~   ^~~~~
```

I don't know much about C.

Comment: Because in second code snippet ```%s``` need starting address of char array. So, ```name``` stores starting address of array. Where as in char ```%c``` needs address as well. In ```char ch;``` ```ch``` won't return address you need to use ```&ch```.

Comment: @Sathvik: `name` does not store an address - name is *converted* to an address as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in C are simply sequences of characters. The `%s` format specifier thus expects a pointer to `char` such that it can write whatever `scanf` reads into the character sequence at the memory location pointed to by that pointer. In your case `name` is a character *array* and not a pointer, but in C you can often use arrays in contexts where pointers are expected, we say that the array *decays* to a pointer to its first member.

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` function takes a pointer of the variable whose value is to be set.

For other types like `int`, we use `&` operator which specifies the address of the variable whereas for char[] the variable `name` is converted to the pointer to the first element of the array so we don't need a `&`.

Comment: `char name[100];` is an array rather than a pointer. It's automatically converted to the pointer to its first element in this and many other cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @HolyBlackCat!!. I understood the mistake and had fixed it. Can you have a look ?

Comment: the name designates the array and is not an address. It is converted to a pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are arrays of chars. Arrays are passed by reference in C.

So when you pass array to the function you actually pass the pointer.